# Django ModelForm dynamic runTIme field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

How would I dynamically add fields on a ModelForm that are not defined on the model at runTime on Django 1.9.7?

I'm aware I can do:

```
  class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
      class Meta:
          model = Example
          # if you don't define the list of fields __all__ won't get the dynamic one
          fields = '__all__'
      MY_CHOICES = (
          ('A', 'Choice A'),
          ('B', 'Choice B'),
      )
      stuff = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MY_CHOICES)
```

But what if I need the choices for example to be gathered at Runtime? For example:

```
  class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
      class Meta:
          model = Example
          fields = '__all__'
      MY_CHOICES = (
          ('A', 'Choice A'),
          ('B', 'Choice B'),
      )
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
          self.stuff = forms.ChoiceField(choices=self.MY_CHOICES)
          # self.fields['stuff'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=self.MY_CHOICES) Also does not work
```

Returns an error of

> Unknown field(s) (stuff) specified for Example.

How would I define a field that is not defined on the Model and that needs to gather the choises for example from a different query?

Thanks.

Edit: [StackTrace](https://pastebin.com/8Ux9Ne5D)

To Reproduce the error simply ask for the field and add the field at runTime, like so:

```
class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Example
        fields = '__all__'
    MY_CHOICES = (
        ('A', 'Choice A'),
        ('B', 'Choice B'),
    )
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.stuff = forms.ChoiceField(choices=self.MY_CHOICES)
        # self.fields['stuff'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=self.MY_CHOICES) Also does not work

class ExampleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            "fields": ("stuff",)
        }),
    )
    form = ExampleForm
```

Comment: I don't think the Model is important for that. stuff is not a field of the model it will be the result of a complex query on other tables  so when on Edit I would get the "ExampleId" and do this query to populate a ChoiceField. And I wanted to manipulate it on the admin as if it was any other field.

Comment: The Model does nothing. It is literally just a Model. No field in the model is relevant to what I want to do because the data is not on the Model. I think this tickcet is exactly what I need. Will give it a shot

Comment: I don't know about `fieldsets`, but just to get it working on the form, can't you define `stuff` like in your first example and then add the `choices` in the `__init__`?

Comment: @PauloAlmeida I think that will be what it needs to be done. Dynamically adding the choices, do you know how that would work if I wanted to do a dynamic filter_horizontal ? please post that as an answer so I can accept. Dynamically adding the choices is the way to go

Comment: You can post the answer and accept it, I think it will be more accurate that way (i.e. you can post exactly what works out in the end). I don't know how it would work with filter_horizontal, I'd have to try it.

Comment: Couldn't get it to work with filter horizontal but populating the choices after worked like a charm for a simple select. Will post an answer soon then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me what was a solution is to just dynamically populate the choices later.

```
class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Example
        fields = '__all__'
    MY_CHOICES = (
        ('A', 'Choice A'),
        ('B', 'Choice B'),
    )
    stuff = forms.ChoiceField()
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['stuff'].choices = self.MY_CHOICES
```

Now my next aim is to be able to make a horizontal filter with data coming not from a model but from another external source.